# How to convert XML into SQL table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I am trying to convert an XML variable to SQL table using `openxml` but I am not getting the result.

```
Declare @List xml = '<List><CNames>One</CNames><CNames>two</CNames></List>'
```

Ideally I want like

```
Cnames -- columname
One
two
```

I am beginner tried google but no luck - TIA

Answer (score 2):

First of all: `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more. Rather use the native methods supported by the XML data type.

Your question is not very clear, but my magic crystall ball told me, that you might be looking for something along this:

```
Declare @List xml = '<List><CNames>One</CNames><CNames>two</CNames></List>';

SELECT A.x.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CName
--INTO dbo.SomeTable
FROM @List.nodes('/List/CNames') A(x);
```

This will return the XML's content as a tabular result.

Just take away the `--` (-> uncomment) before the `INTO` and you will find a new table `SomeTable` among your database's tables with this content.

If this does not help you, please try to use the edit option of your answer and add some more details.

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thank you :)